# how invoke js on client side from server side

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, rest, client-server

I want to make a chat on site but don't know how to contact from server to js.

I want to use REST and know how send request to server and receive callback. How invoke js from server?

On server site I want to use Java or Groovy as client side AngularJs.

How invoke js on client side from server side?

Comment: Try looking into Websockets, if you're trying to write a chat client

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can you recommend js framework to work with Websockets if it possible more friendly with angularJs

Comment: I don't have much experience with it but I hear socket.io is great and is emerging as a de facto standard for websockets in javascript.